# iPhone - Why did all interface went a little bit down

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I changed something in my cocoa-touch application and all interface went down for something like 20 pixels. And at one view there is a white bar at the top (it has no background color, although view itself has one). And in the interface builder nothing changed - everything looks as it should look.

Anyone has an idea why could this happen? It would take me a while to manually change positioning of items on my view.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting you changed the simulated metrics in interface builder.

See Also: [iPhone NavigationController - same view pushed, different layouts received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575794/iphone-navigationcontroller-same-view-pushed-different-layouts-received)